# Is the law of conservation of momentum valid during long collision times

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Suppose that two particles (1) and (2) collide, and (1) experiences a force $\mathbf S_{12}$ from particle (2) and the sum of all the other possible forces as $\mathbf F_1$. Then, the impulse on (1) during the collision time interval $[0, \tau]$ can be written as 
$$
\Delta \mathbf p_1 = \int_0^\tau \mathbf S_{12} + \mathbf F_1 dt
$$
and in the same way
$$
\Delta \mathbf p_2 = \int_0^\tau \mathbf S_{21} + \mathbf F_{2} dt.
$$

Let's now look at the whole system consisting of (1) and (2), the impulse can be expressed as 
$$
\Delta \mathbf p = \int_0^\tau \mathbf S_{12} + \mathbf F_1 + \mathbf S_{21} + \mathbf F_2 dt
$$ 
and since $\mathbf S_{12} + \mathbf S_{21} = \mathbf 0$ by Newtons third law we get
\begin{align}
\Delta \mathbf p = \int_0^\tau \mathbf F_1 + \mathbf F_2 dt.
\end{align}

Assuming that $\mathbf F_1, \mathbf F_2$ are collision time independent, then as $\tau \to 0$ we get that
$$
\left\lvert \int_0^\tau \mathbf F dt \right\rvert \leq \lvert \mathbf F_{\text{max}} \rvert \tau\to0
$$ 
that is to say their contribution to the change in momentum is negligible for very small $\tau$.

So assuming that $\tau$ is small, we arrive at law of conservation of momentum
$$
\Delta \mathbf p = 0.
$$

- My question is what happens if $\tau$ is not small enough for us to able to approximate $\mathbf F_1 + \mathbf F_2$ as $\mathbf 0$, and if so how small does $\tau$ need to be? Does the conservation of momentum always apply, even when the collision takes a long time?

Comment: I'm a little confused; if there are external forces $\vec{F}_1$ and $\vec{F}_2$ to the system of the two particles whose sum is non-zero, then the momentum of that system is not conserved. If $\tau$ is small, then okay, their impulse will also be small (and perhaps negligible), but the momentum of the system is still not a conserved quantity.

Comment: Ah you're right. In my textbook it is never explicitly said that a prerequisite for the the law to hold was for the system to be close; It is only derived in a similar fashion to what I wrote above, saying that it is always the case that $\mathbf F$ will be much smaller than the collision forces so are always "negligible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, conservation of momentum always applies in a closed system. However forces $\mathbf F_1$ and $\mathbf F_2$ are external forces, so the system will not be closed until it includes the source of those forces. Often that is the Earth, and it is rare to be able to observe any momentum change in the Earth. If the time of the collision is small enough then our approximation is that the momentum of the colliding objects is constant. When the time of collision is long enough and the external forces are large enough then conservation of momentum, while still true, may not be useful in solving the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What would the derivation look like if we were to include the Earth in our model?

Comment: $\Delta \mathbf p_E = -\int_0^\tau \mathbf F_1 + \mathbf F_2 dt$ by Newton's 3rd Law. The final result would be $\Delta\mathbf p_1+\Delta\mathbf p_2 + \Delta\mathbf p_E = 0$. Unfortunately we can't get a useful handle on $\Delta\mathbf p_E$